# request for member " " in something not a structure or union? in Flex&Bison

Tags: gcc, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

in my final project left me several codes, one of them is this for flex & bison.
The problem is that gcc returns me the message **"request for member '*db*' in something not a structure or union"** in bison file ...
I do not know how to fix this, I find examples of solutions but none works for me.
I hope I can help, thanks in advance.

Flex file:

```
%{
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "y.tab.h"
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
%}
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno
digit   [0-9]
blank   [\t]
sign    [+-/*]
other   .

%%

{digit}+            { sscanf(yytext, "%lf", &yylval.db); return NUMBER;}
{digit}+\.{digit}*  { sscanf(yytext, "%lf", &yylval.db); return NUMBER;}
\.{digit}+          { sscanf(yytext, "%lf", &yylval.db); return NUMBER;} 
sign                return *yytext;
{blank}+            ; 
{other}             return yytext[0];


%%

int main()
{
 if (yyparse()==0){
 printf("\n NO ERROR");}
 return 0;
}

int yyerror(char * mensaje)
{
 printf("\n AND STOP");
 printf("\n ERROR: %s",mensaje);
 printf("\n ERROR LINE: %d",yylineno);
 return 0;
}
```

Bison File:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h> 
    char result[100];
%}

%union { double db; int i; }
%token NUMBER
%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'
%left '(' ')'
%nonassoc UMINUS 
%type<db> list NUMBER
%type<i> expression
%start list

%%

list    : expression { printf("\nResultado: %5g\n",$$.db);} 
        ;
expression  : expression '+' expression { $$.db = $1.db + $3.db; }
            | expression '-' expression { $$.db = $1.db - $3.db; }
            | expression '*' expression { $$.db = $1.db * $3.db; }
            | expression '/' expression {  if ($3.db==(double)0) yyerror("Division por cero\n");    
                                           else  $$.db = $1.db / $3.db; }
            | '-' expression %prec UMINUS { $$.db = -$2.db; }
            | '(' expression ')'                   { $$.db = $2.db; }
            | NUMBER                            { $$.db = $1.db; } 
            ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare that `expression` has type `i` (`%type<i> expression`), you're telling bison that wherever you've put an expression, the stack value should be the `.i` variant. So in all of the `expression` productions, `$$` already represents the `.i` union member; if you write an explicit `.db`, then you end up generating `yylval.i.db`. But `yylval.i` is an int, which is not a strut or a union and therefore cannot have any members.

I strongly suspect that you intended the type of `expression` to be `db`, but whatever it is, you don't have to (and in fact cannot) explicitly specify the union member in your action.